# extend Oeis A152211 for more consecutive increasing terms

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[A152211](http://oeis.org/A152211/list) is a very uneven sequence !

If you have powerful computations resources, find a longest consecutive list of increasing terms

What algorithm could we use ?

Comment: why ? what is the particular interest  of this sequence ?

Comment: It is just a test for an experimenter to see how much time can be spent to find such a small number.  There are many, many other sequences at OEIS in which this question could be asked.  There are also many, many sequences in which other questions have not been asked.  This could be a whole new field for curious experimenters....as available.  One needs to like experimenting and asking the question "What would happen if I did this?"

Comment: I setted 12 machines on 1 sequence during weeks until I found a trick to get the result in 10 sec. Now, I prefer to spend time searching tricks. And you know the carbon issue ... :)

Comment: Well, that's certainly obvious=use the tricks to save time while exploring sequences to find the miraculous.  Why be on this planet unless one can find the miraculous?  The carbon issue is a direct result of Late Capitalism and has nothing to do with using a computer to find the miraculous.

Comment: the miracle would be to get 8 13 24 28 35 (4) at the azerbaidjan lotto tonight.

Comment: Gambling is sinful...call yourself a Christian, indeed!!  If you won that lotto you could afford to get someone with a large, fast computer to explore A152211.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment
rather than an answer.

The sequence is
$s(n)
=n\sigma_0(n)+\sigma_1(n)
$
where
$\sigma_k(n)
=\sum_{d|n} d^k
$,
so that
$s(n)
=\sum_{d|n} (n+d)
$.

Actually,
I think a more interesting sequence
would be
$t(n)
=n\sigma_0(n)-2\sigma_1(n)
=\sum_{d|n} (n-2d)
$
as I think its
fluctuations around zero
would be complicated.
Here are the first 15 values
according to Wolfy:
{{1, -1}, {2, -2}, {3, -2}, {4, -2}, {5, -2}, {6, 0}, {7, -2}, {8, 2}, {9, 1}, {10, 4}, {11, -2}, {12, 16}, {13, -2}, {14, 8}, {15, 12}}.

Note that
for prime $p$,
$s(p)
=p\sigma_0(p)+\sigma_1(p)
=2p+p+1
=3p+1
$
and
$t(p)
=2p-2(p+1)
=-2
$.

Note that
the average order
of
$\sigma_0(n)$
is
$\ln(n)
$
and
the average order
of
$\sigma_1(n)$
is
$n\pi^2/6
$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function),
so,
if the two sums are correlated,
the average value of
$s(n)$
is
$n(\ln(n)+\pi^2/6)
$
and
the average value of
$t(n)$
is
$n(\ln(n)-\pi^2/3)
$.

From looking at
the plot produced
by Wolfy,
I would conjecture that
$t(n) \ge 0$
if $n$ is not a prime.

Comment: If you look at the brief list for A152211 you see very small number of consecutive increasing terms.  Extend this by a few hundred terms to see if there is NO improvement in the lengths of the runs of increasing terms.  If not, then looks like little of excitement will be found.

Comment: All you have to do is look at the list of terms.  You will see for a(25)=106, followed by 146,148,224 to get four consecutive increasing terms.  All you have to do is to see if there's some a(k) with MORE than four consecutive increasing terms.  (How can this be in any way "unclear"?

Comment: Can what you say possibly be true?  How can you NOT understand what is being asked?  If I said merely extend the sequence to find a list of consecutive terms that are all increasing and greater than four in number, would this be beyond your ability to understand?  Perhaps I could send in a video to clarify all this (to you) mystery?

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking"?  I suspect sleeplessness, drugs or alcohol.